# Сохранение изображения из canvas Canvas.toDataURL();

Tags: javascript, html5, изображения, canvas

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему когда мы используем функцию Canvas.toDataURL();  и отрисовываем на холсте простые фигуры, типа кривых Безье. Я получаю рабочую ссылку в формате base 64.

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="200" style="display:none;"></canvas>
<img id="canvasImg" alt="Right click to save me!">
<script>
  var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

  // draw cloud
  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(170, 80);
  context.bezierCurveTo(130, 100, 130, 150, 230, 150);
  context.bezierCurveTo(250, 180, 320, 180, 340, 150);
  context.bezierCurveTo(420, 150, 420, 120, 390, 100);
  context.bezierCurveTo(430, 40, 370, 30, 340, 50);
  context.bezierCurveTo(320, 5, 250, 20, 250, 50);
  context.bezierCurveTo(200, 5, 150, 20, 170, 80);
  context.closePath();
  context.lineWidth = 5;
  context.fillStyle = '#8ED6FF';
  context.fill();
  context.strokeStyle = '#0000ff';
  context.stroke();

  // save canvas image as data url (png format by default)
  var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();

  // set canvasImg image src to dataURL
  // so it can be saved as an image
  document.getElementById('canvasImg').src = dataURL;

</script>
```

Но как только пытаюсь загрузить картинку открывается белый экран. И base64 url не меняется при смене разных картинок. Он меняется, только в случае изменения ширины и высоты элемента canvas. Что наводит на мысль, что картинка просто не отрисовывается на холсте, хотя в браузере она видна. Как быть?

```
<a id="img"><p>Download</p></a>
 <canvas id="can" width="600" height="300"></canvas>
    <script>    
        var example = document.getElementById('can');
        ctx = example.getContext('2d'); 
        pic = new Image();             

        pic.onload = function() 
        {    
            ctx.drawImage(pic, 0, 0); 
        }
        pic.src = '1.jpg';
        var canvas = document.getElementById('can');
        var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        document.getElementById('img').href = dataURL;
        document.write(dataURL);

  </script>
```

Скажите, может я неправильно отрисовываю картинку на холсте. И если таким способом получить ссылку на картинку нельзя, подскажите действенный способ, любой подойдет, даже самый медленный и громоздкий.

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, потому что операция асинхронная, а ты белый холст экспортируешь.

Надо так:

```
var example = document.getElementById('can');
ctx = example.getContext('2d'); 
pic = new Image();             
pic.onload = function() 
{    
    ctx.drawImage(pic, 0, 0); 
    var canvas = document.getElementById('can');
    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    document.getElementById('img').href = dataURL;
}
pic.src = "https://www.google.ru/images/srpr/logo11w.png";
```

> Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported.

Думаю, этого не будет, если картинка будет грузиться с твоего же сайта.

Но всё равно есть проблемка. У data uri есть ограничение длины.

Comment: Это гениально :D, работает, спустя 13 часов я подобрался к ответу. Спасибо! Все было так просто

Comment: На счет ограничения длинны, можно ли делить большое изображение на 4 части, получать 4 разных data url? А потом собирать с помощью php или js, вопрос только как?

Comment: @KiZZek, было что-то про blob uri, но я не помню. Думаю, стоит в том направлении покапать.